# How to index innodb text in mysql?

Tags: mysql, hash, indexing, innodb

I'm trying to index a text field in mysql innodb-table and seems like hash index is the way to go like this:

```
CREATE INDEX teksti_index USING HASH ON maili_teksti(teksti(100));
```

So, does this mean that mysql takes first 100 characters of the field and calculates the hash (and then indexes the hash).  Is the size of the index same if I change the number 100 to 200?

And ... is this a right way to go if I want to optimize this kind of commands:

```
SELECT count(*) from teksti where teksti='random text';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When dealing with `CHAR`, `VARCHAR`, and `TEXT` columns (as you are dealing with `TEXT`), the prefix-length you assign when creating the index will create a hash using the *first X characters* - exactly how you're thinking ([source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html)).

When dealing with a standard index, changing the size of the data that's indexed should also change the size of the index (i.e. - adding characters should increase the index; removing should decrease). When dealing with a HASH-index, and this is a guess because I cannot find specific documentation regarding it, I would assume that it *doesn't* increase (at least, not by much) due to the nature of hashing-algorithms.

HASH-indexes are only applied to the `=` and `<=>` operators, so your sample usage of `teksti='random text'` is perfect for this type of index ([source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html)). If you need to use other operators, such as the `LIKE`, `<` or `>` operators, you may have to consider switching to a `B-TREE` index instead.

As a complete alternative option, you could check out [`FULLTEXT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) index. This provides a large amount of matching capabilities, though it's fairly robust and may be *too much*. The documentation on the [`Full-Text Search Functions`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) page states that `FULLTEXT` can only be used with MyISAM, *however*, `Section 14.2.4.12.3` on the [`InnoDB Table and Index`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-table-and-index.html) documentation page covers `FULLTEXT` indexes with InnoDB - so, this may or may not be available =P.

Comment: Thank you for your very professional and profound answer! I feel happy  and secure to go on now :)